# QGIS: v.rast.stats not adding columns

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

In QGIS (3.16.14-Hannover), I have a layer of polygons as well as a raster layer, and I would like to compute for each polygon the average value of the corresponding raster area.

As far as I gathered, I can use `v.rast.stats` from the GRASS "Processing Toolbox" for this.

I've been able to run the above with the chosen inputs, and a new "Rast Stats" vector layer with the same shape as the input one gets created, however there are no added columns when I go into the attribute table, even though I entered a column prefix for the new attribute, and selected `average` in the methods to use.

EDIT: the raster file is [this one](https://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_MT_GLOBE_R2019A/GHS_POP_E2015_GLOBE_R2019A_54009_250/V1-0/GHS_POP_E2015_GLOBE_R2019A_54009_250_V1_0.zip), and a sample of the vector layer can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As6P90LZAjmzgSjJFjE1Nf38uk1X?e=KhMnSt).

EDIT2: adding the `v.rast.stats` output:

```
QGIS version: 3.10.5-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 984615fe1e
Qt version: 5.12.3
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.rast.stats' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column_prefix' : 'vrspopd', 'map' : '/Users/msp/data/qgis_vpop/voronoi_ch_mollweide/voronoi_ch_mollweide.gpkg', 'method' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'percentile' : 90, 'raster' : '/Users/msp/data/population/ghsl/GHS_POP_E2015_GLOBE_R2019A_54009_250_V1_0/GHS_POP_E2015_GLOBE_R2019A_54009_250_V1_0.tif' }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/Users/msp/data/voronoi_ch_mollweide/voronoi_ch_mollweide.gpkg" output="vector_61b068c01c6ad2" --overwrite -o
r.external input="/Users/msp/data/population/ghsl/GHS_POP_E2015_GLOBE_R2019A_54009_250_V1_0/GHS_POP_E2015_GLOBE_R2019A_54009_250_V1_0.tif" band=1 output="rast_61b068c01c7923" --overwrite -o
g.region n=9000000.0 s=-9000000.0 e=18041000.0 w=-18041000.0 res=250.0
v.rast.stats -c map=vector_61b068c01c6ad2 raster=rast_61b068c01c7923 column_prefix="vrspopd" method="number,minimum,maximum,range,average,stddev,variance,coeff_var,sum,first_quartile,median,third_quartile,percentile" percentile=90 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="vector_61b068c01c6ad2" output="/private/var/folders/1y/mz55z62j2zq07mktg94rf6qr0000gn/T/processing_8e63def137714cc482f1069ed44118ed/5d1fe8dffaf14c6481bf238633e89b64/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
Executing </private/var/folders/1y/mz55z62j2zq07mktg94rf6qr0000gn/T/processing_8e63def137714cc482f1069ed44118ed/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
WARNING: Datum <unknown> not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
WARNING: Datum <unknown> not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <outputf4943157d39b4babbcf42c2488471591> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <outputf4943157d39b4babbcf42c2488471591>...
Column name <cat> renamed to <cat_>
Column name <cat_> renamed to <cat__1>
Importing 2865 features (OGR layer <outputf4943157d39b4babbcf42c2488471591>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <outputf4943157d39b4babbcf42c2488471591>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
2865 input polygons
Total area: 4.12365E+10 (2866 areas)
Area without category: 7.66746E+06 (1 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <vector_61b068c01c6ad2@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10000..
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
Attaching centroids...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_61b068c01c7923> created.
ImportError: No module named site
Exporting 2866 areas (may take some time)...
5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..95..100
WARNING: 1 feature without category was skipped. Features without category are written only when -c flag is given.
v.out.ogr complete. 2865 features (Polygon type) written to <vector_61b068c01c6ad2> (GPKG format).
Execution of </private/var/folders/1y/mz55z62j2zq07mktg94rf6qr0000gn/T/processing_8e63def137714cc482f1069ed44118ed/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2207, in <module>
main()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2155, in main
clean_all()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 1789, in clean_all
gsetup.clean_default_db()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass/script/setup.py", line 220, in clean_default_db
conn = gdb.db_connection()
File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass/script/db.py", line 108, in db_connection
nuldev = file(os.devnull, 'w')
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/grass76.sh: line 20: /private/var/folders/1y/mz55z62j2zq07mktg94rf6qr0000gn/T/processing_8e63def137714cc482f1069ed44118ed/grassdata/temp_location/PERMANENT: is a directory
Execution completed in 196.22 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.rast.stats' finished
```

EDIT3: screenshot of `v.rast.stats` dialog:

[image]

Comment: Both layers have the same CRS? If not, reproject at least one layer that they have the same CRS

Comment: @Babel yes, both layers have the World_Mollweide CRS.

Comment: Can you share your data, at least a part of it?

Comment: Upload it to a cloud service and share the link here

Comment: By the way: what is the "average of raster area"? You want to calculate the area of the polygons? Or raster values: the mean of the pixel values inside the polygon?

Comment: @Babel done. Yes I would like for each polygon to compute the average of the covered pixel values (and ultimately multiply that average by the area of the polygon)

Comment: OK, so then you simply want to get the average of the pixels per polygon - this has nothing to do with area as far as it concerns the workflow here - I think this was misleading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132139/discussion-between-mspices-and-babel).

Comment: Did you also consider zonal statistics?

Comment: You have all 13 options selected for `methods to use` - maybe just select the one you really need and deselect all others.

Comment: @Babel I did initially, then I tried with the default settings (all 13 options) to see if that would work - but the outcome was the same.

Answer (score 2):

**How to find the error**

It is always worth having a closer look at error messages. When I run `v.rast.stats` with your data, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Wrong field type for fid
FEHLER: Unable to create column <fid>
```

**How to solve the problem**

The `fid` attribute in your polygon layer is of field type `double` (when it should be integer). Simply deleting the `fid` field solves the problem.

If you want to keep the `fid`, copy it to a new field using field calculator, set field type for the new field you create to `integer` and set the expression to `fid`.

**Recommended alternative**

By the way: instead of `v.rast.stats`, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Zonal Statistics` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics)): it was a lot faster: The GRASS tool took like 15 minutes, Zonal Statistics only 0.1 seconds(!) - with the same results.

**Screenshot**

*When deleting the `fid`, QGIS automatically creates a new one - with different values, however:*

[image]

Comment: thank you - Zonal statistics indeed works fine! Concerning the `fid` field: this seems to have happened when I selected a part of my dataset for sharing. The original has type `qlonglong`.

Comment: OK - so deleting the fid works for you?

Comment: What I mean is that the type of the `fid` field isn't the cause of v.rast.stats failing. But since Zonal statistics is much easier and faster I'll just use that.

Comment: OK, great to hear. As I told you, deleting the `fid` in my case, using your data, solved the problem: the screenshot was created using `v.rast.stats`, so I'm not sure what else went wrong in your case. However, the raster is a huge, worldwide dataset. Maybe clipping it to your area of interest could speed up processing?

Comment: That could be - I've also added the output log for `v.rast.stats` with my original vector layer, indeed it contains some error messages but I don't know how to interpret them.

Comment: How does your `v.rast.stats` dialog window (where you define the inputs) look like? Can you post a screenshot? And did you try re-runing it without the `fid` field (as this worked in my case)?

Comment: I tried deleting the `fid` field in the voronoi_small sample, and re-running `v.rast.stats`, but the result was the same: the resulting layer "Rast stats" contained no additional columns.

Comment: It's strange because in my case, I could run it without problems and it produced the correct output. There must be something with your settings, installation etc...?